# How to dump an empty array using Symfony Yaml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'm trying to use the [Symfony Yaml](http://symfony.com/doc/curent/components/yaml/introduction.html) `dump` function to output some nested php array data.

```
use \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

echo Yaml::dump([
    'arr'=>[],
    'foo'=>'bar',
]);
```

However, the dumped YAML contains an empty object:

```
arr: {  }
foo: bar
```

while I want an empty list:

```
arr: []
foo: bar
```

I tried using the `Yaml::DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP` flag, using the `ArrayObject` instead of array literals, and using an `EmptyIterator`, all to no avail.

I found two closed bugs related to this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9870 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15781, but the solutions there don't seem to work, or are a bit too hacky and brittle for my taste (str_replace on the YAML output, brrrr)

I have a simple testcase with what I tried so far: https://github.com/ComaVN/php-yaml-empty-array

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: what version of Symfony? I think this may have been addressed in 3.1?

Comment: I encountered it in 2.3, but the problem still occurs with the latest version of symfony/yaml (v3.1.2, see my testcase)

Comment: see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17578 and http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-customizable-yaml-parsing-and-dumping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Symfony 3.3 (released May 2017) you can use the new `Yaml::DUMP_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_SEQUENCE` option:

```
Yaml::dump($object, 2, 4, Yaml::DUMP_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_SEQUENCE);
```

This feature was added in [PR 21471](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21471).

Comment: Brilliant!  Adding `"symfony/yaml": "^3.3@dev"` to my composer.json allowed me to use this feature, and thus create swagger-ui compatible yaml.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting that in some form quotes, so that it can be extracted at a later time?

```
'arr'=>'[]',
```